# Converting array of strings to 2D array of codes sped up by Numba

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

I want to perform the following operation on a string and then apply that on an array of strings. I want to speed this operation up using Numba because it will be done on >1 million strings often. I have tried adding the `@vectorize` decorator to the function but I keep running into errors. Is there anyway to speed this up or will regular python be my only option?

```
def char_to_code(char):
    asc = ord(char)
    if asc >= 123:
        if asc <= 126:
            asc = asc - 122 + 28
    elif asc >= 97:
        asc = asc - 96 + 300
    elif asc >= 91:
        asc = asc - 90 + 22
    elif asc >= 65:
        asc = asc - 64 + 200
    elif asc >= 58:
        asc = asc - 57 + 15
    elif asc >= 48:
        asc = asc - 47 + 100
    elif asc >= 32:
        asc -= 32
    return asc
```

EDIT:
I wrote the program like this:

```
from numba import vectorize
import numpy as np

@vectorize
def char_to_code(char):
    asc = ord(char)
    if asc >= 123:
        if asc <= 126:
            asc = asc - 122 + 28
    elif asc >= 97:
        asc = asc - 96 + 300
    elif asc >= 91:
        asc = asc - 90 + 22
    elif asc >= 65:
        asc = asc - 64 + 200
    elif asc >= 58:
        asc = asc - 57 + 15
    elif asc >= 48:
        asc = asc - 47 + 100
    elif asc >= 32:
        asc -= 32
    return asc

char_to_code(np.array(list('bobobobob')))
```

And got the following error when running the program.

```
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "Desktop\ODC 2.0\functions.py", line 771:
@vectorize
def char_to_code(char):
^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/samebhar/Desktop/ODC 2.0/functions.py", line 790, in <module>
    char_to_code('bobobobob')
  File "C:\Users\samebhar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\dufunc.py", line 201, in _compile_for_args
    return self._compile_for_argtys(tuple(argtys))
  File "C:\Users\samebhar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\dufunc.py", line 220, in _compile_for_argtys
    actual_sig = ufuncbuilder._finalize_ufunc_signature(
  File "C:\Users\samebhar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\ufuncbuilder.py", line 157, in _finalize_ufunc_signature
    raise TypeError("return type must be specified for object mode")
TypeError: return type must be specified for object mode
PS C:\Users\samebhar>
```

I would like the function to work like a vectorized operation on a Numpy array of characters or directly a string if possible to make it fast. So it should return

```
[302, 315, 302, 315, 302, 315, 302, 315, 302]
```

after the vectorized operation is complete on each element of the array.

(ANY OTHER WAY OF SPEEDING THIS UP IS WELCOME)

Comment: Please describe what error you are getting and what behavior you are expecting to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a look-up table using [maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans):

```
MAX = 127
dictionary = {chr(code): char_to_code(chr(code)) for code in range(MAX)}
table = str.maketrans(dictionary)
```

and then use [translate()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate):

```
>>> "Hello, world!".translate(table)
'ÐıĸĸĻ\x0c\x00ŃĻľĸİ\x01'
```